# Custom wordpress comments css class

Tags: wordpress, class, function, filter

Is there a way to add a custom class to comments that is a "reply comment" of a parent comment ?

*Note: my template use 'max_depth' => '1'.

Output code:

```
<div>
  <div class="comment-1"></div> // comment 1
    <div class="comment-2"></div> // reply 1
    <div class="comment-3"></a functiondiv> // reply 2
  <div class="comment-4"> // comment 2
</div>
```

I need a class for replies like:

```
<div>
  <div class="comment-1"></div> // comment 1
    <div class="comment-2" class="reply"></div> // reply 1
    <div class="comment-3" class="reply"></div> // reply 2
  <div class="comment-4"> // comment 2
</div>
```

A filter or a function ?

**Edit:**
Code that loops the comments is:

1. In `comments.php`
   wp_list_comments(array('style' => 'div', 'type' => 'comment', 'max_depth' => '1' , 'callback' => 'comments_template'));
2. In `functions.php`
   http://pastebin.com/4T5DiZY4

Comment: Can you give the code that loops the comments?

Comment: I just edited the main post. Please check it out. I would appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`comment_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/comment_class) has a filter with the same name [`comment_class`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/comment_class?version=3.4&file=wp-includes/comment-template.php)

```
function parent_comment_SE_14130085($classes, $class, $comment_id, $post_id) {
    $cur_comment = get_comment($comment_id);

    if ( ! empty( $cur_comment->comment_parent ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'nested';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('comment_class', 'parent_comment_SE_14130085', 10, 4);
```

Comment: I've put this code in functions.php but I got some "missing argument" errors in each comment - "for parent_comment_SE_14130085()".

Comment: OK, I just fixed this error. Now works perfect, exactly what I needed :) Thanks for your time.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot the args of the `add_filter` updated my answer